# Javascript split() method behaving unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I can't seem to get the file extension included in my split() array.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="audInput" onchange="loadAud()" autocomplete="off"><br>

<textarea id="txtArea" rows="4" cols="50" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
function loadAud() {

  var fileInput = document.getElementById('audInput');   
  var filename = fileInput.files[0].name;

  var fileSplit = filename.split(".");
  var ext = fileSplit.pop();
  
  document.getElementById("txtArea").value = filename + "\n" + fileSplit+ "\n" + ext;
```

**Filename:**

```
this.is.a.test.mp3
```

**Textarea value:**

> this.is.a.test.mp3
>
> this,is,a,test
>
> mp3

Why isn't the second line "this, is, a test, mp3"?
The pop() method seems to be working as expected because it returns "mp3".

Comment: Because `pop` removes the element it pops off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`.pop()`](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1796-javascript-array-methods-unshift-shift-push-and-pop.htm) returns what it removes from the array get it's return when chaining it to `split()`.

```
var fileSplit = filename.split(".").pop();
```

#### Demo

```js
var filename = 'index.html';


var fileSplit = filename.split(".").pop();

console.log(fileSplit);
```

Comment: What ended up working for me was:   var fileSplit = filename.split(".");   var ext = filename.split(".").pop();

Comment: Oopps sorry about that, I was fixated on that particular part of the code but not its entirety. I'm glad you got it ok, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Cause `.pop()` removes the element from the array. May do:

```
var ext = fileSplit[ fileSplit.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the **[official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop).**

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element.
>
> **This method changes the length of the array**.

So you may have to remove the last element after the split operation :

```js
var fileSplit = "this.is.a.test.mp3".split(".");

console.log(fileSplit + "\n" + fileSplit.pop());
```